# How to print contents of file as well as filename in linux using some adhoc command

Tags: awk, text-processing, cat

I have multiple files starting with `DUMP_*`.
Each file has data for a particular dump.
I want to print filename as well as contents of file in stdout

The expected output should be

```
FILENAME
ALL CONTENTS OF FILE
and so on
```

Closest thing I have tried is

```
cat $(ll DUMP_* | awk -F ' ' '{print $9}' ) | less
```

With this I am not able to figure out which content belongs to which file. 
Also, I am reluctant to use a shell script, an adhoc command is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is not fully in line with your expectations, but you see the link between a filename and its content even better:

Situation:

```
Prompt>cat DUMP_1
Info
More Info
Prompt>cat DUMP_2
Info
```

Solution:

```
Prompt>grep "" DUMP_*
DUMP_1:Info
DUMP_1:More Info
DUMP_2:Info
```